# NiceTabular with stretched text

Tags: nicematrix

Is there a way to get in a `NiceTabular` the text stretched up to the column width?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{wl{20em}}
Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi \\
quam commodi culpa quaerat sunt
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

I know about `\makebox[\mywidth][s]{my text}` but isn't there any simpler solution with tabulars?

As I often use `tikz`, the solution should also work with `\node`. `NiceTabular` does well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `tabularray` package instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={Q[20em]},
  cell{1}{1-2} = {cmd=\makebox[\linewidth][s]}
}
Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi \\
quam commodi culpa quaerat sunt\\
\end{tblr}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.17 of 2023/03/31), you can use in `{NiceTabular}` the columns standard columns `w{s}{...}` and `W{s}{...}` (of the package `array`) with the expected output.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{w{s}{20em}}
Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi \\
quam commodi culpa quaerat sunt
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as with `{tabular}` (see below).

---

You probably want to use the column type `w{s}{...}` of `{tabular}` (as defined by the package `array`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{w{s}{20em}}
Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi \\
quam commodi culpa quaerat sunt
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Since `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is an extension of `{tabular}` (of `array`), the same should work with `{NiceTabular}`. However, it does not. That may be considered as a bug. I will try to solve that bug (I'm the author of `nicematrix`).